# File Upload through rest and html as client

Tags: java, html, rest, multipartform-data, fileinputstream

i just want to upload a file using jersey rest service and Jquery ajax as client here is my code
1. HTML

```
<form action="rest/file/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <p>
    Select a file : <input type="file" name="file" />
   </p>

   <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
</form>
```

2.Rest Service

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream stream) {

    String uploadedFileLocation = "E:\\\\uploaded\\test.jpg";
    //Session s = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
    //InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(<< String to parse >>);
    //MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(s, stream);
    //Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
    // save it



    writeToFile(stream, uploadedFileLocation);


    String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

    try {

        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}

// save uploaded file to new location
private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        String uploadedFileLocation) {

    try {
        byte[] image = IOUtils.toByteArray(uploadedInputStream);


        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));

        IOUtils.write(image, out);

        /*int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }*/
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

its working but stream includes this line also

```
-----------------------------7dd3b827a0ddc
```

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Jellyfish.jpg"
Content-Type: image/pjpeg

how to remove this from inputstream?
need expertise answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This string that you see is a kind of identifier added by the server to mark the start and end of the data uploaded in a form. If you dump the whole data in a text file, it will show something like this in your text file.

```
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-----------------------------7dd3b827a0ddc
Content-Length: 29278

-----------------------------7dd3b827a0ddc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="txt1"

Some Sample Text
-----------------------------7dd3b827a0ddc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Jellyfish.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg

(Binary data not shown)
-----------------------------7dd3b827a0ddc--
```

The value of the boundary i.e. -----------------------------7dd3b827a0ddc is a marker that multipart form data uses to identify the start and end of data for all fields in your overall upload.

I created this sample file for you assuming one file upload and a input text named txt1.

On the data file you can see the "boundary" in header and then the boundary being used to separate the two fields in the form data. Notice the extra "--" on the last boundary. That marks the end of the file.

You need to manually parse the data and extract all of the fields. The data between the markers where you have filename="Jellyfish.jpg" is the actual binary data uploaded for your image. When you extract that data (excluding the "Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Jellyfish.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg") from between the two markers and save that data as "Jellyfish.jpg"; this will be your image.